# SendInfoTo(NetState, bool, bool)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Tags: c#

This could be the easiest fix for someone who has a clue what they're doing. for me, someone who has no idea due to only still learning the basics; am stumped on this. I came to this site to further my learning with C# since every error I google to see what's going on, leads me here. Anyways, here are my lines that are contributing to the error along with the error itself.

****CODE****

```
        public override void SendInfoTo(NetState state, bool sendOplPacket)
    {
        if (state.Mobile != null && ((m_Placer != null && state.Mobile.Serial.Equals(m_Placer.Serial)) || state.Mobile.AccessLevel >= AccessLevel.Administrator))
            SendInfoTo(state, sendOplPacket, false);
    }

    void SendInfoTo(NetState state, bool sendOplPacket, bool doChecks)
    {
        if (doChecks)
        {
            if (state.Mobile == null ||
                ((m_Placer == null || !state.Mobile.Serial.Equals(m_Placer.Serial)) &&
                 state.Mobile.AccessLevel < AccessLevel.Administrator))
                return false;
        }
```

****ERROR****

> Since 'BaseFactionTrap.SendInfoTo(NetState, bool, bool)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

The error is coming from the "return false;" line at the end of the code. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the void function is returning false. If you need to check whether it works, maybe make it bool SendInfoTo?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `return;`?

Comment: `return false;` compiled with 0 errors, but it causes problems with the gameplay.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `SendInfoTo` is declared as `void`.  That means it can not return any value.

But you are trying to return `false`.  This is not possible, so hence the error.

You must either declare the method with a return statement.  e.g.

```
bool SendInfoTo(NetState state, bool sendOplPacket, bool doChecks)
{
...
}
```

Or not return anything.

But you should then do something with this returned value

Comment: After changing `void SendInfoTo(NetState state, bool sendOplPacket, bool doChecks)` to `bool SendInfoTo(NetState state, bool sendOplPacket, bool doChecks)` I get this error. I tried to play around with it myself before reverting back here but no luck.  "SendInfoTo(NetState, bool, bool)': not all code paths return a value"